# Why take separative quotient in forcing?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In many expositions of topics on forcing, the poset is assumed to be separative, otherwise we pass to the separative quotient. For example, this is the convention taken in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03235) introduction to forcing by Moore, Handbook chapter by Abraham, and the one by Cummings. But I don't really understand the reason behind that. There are certainly some results such as equivalence between Baire and not adding $\omega$-sequences that only hold for separative posets, and also $p\Vdash q\in\dot{G}$ is equivalent to $p\leq q$, but are these essential? In particular, are there any serious issues if we don't take separative quotient at each step when defining iterated forcing?

Comment: I believe it is just for technical convenience: There is no need to distinguish compatible conditions because all generic filters contain both of two compatible conditions or not both.

Comment: @HanulJeon Not taking quotient feels way more convenient to me...On the other extreme, Boolean completion identifies all equivalent *sets*, so why not take Boolean completion

Comment: I saw references considering the Boolean completion instead, but most forcings are described in terms of partial orders and not their Boolean completions. On the other hand, many natural examples of forcing are separative.